# smack connection using servlets

Tags: java, facebook, servlets, chat, smack

Here I am  connecting to  facebook using smack and servlets ,I can able to send and receive chat messages.
But  here connection object is instance variable(not thread-safe),so all the users are getting same connection object.

If we declare XMPPConnection object inside doGet() method we have to take connection every time 
when the user send chat message.

provide some solution for my problem.

```
public class Home_page_action extends HttpServlet  implements MessageListener{

 public XMPPConnection connection;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

               if(connection!=null)
               {connection.connect("uname","password");}
               else{
               //send message code to target user
                }


              }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make some class to maintain pool of your connection and every time you have to just call getInstance of that class..

Comment: you mean just like connectionPooling?

Comment: What is your requirement? Do you want to create new connection per user or per request ?

Comment: new connection per user

Comment: than you can create map like Map<User,XMPPConnection> which will be in cache memory..simple..

Comment: Thank you sir for user patience.Finally my assumption is- when where user login I have to  keep username and XMPPConnectionobject in Map and also username in session.when ever user wants XMPPConnectionobject ,he can browse the Map for his connection and do something with connection.

Comment: exactly..and one session destroy, you can delete that entry

Comment: niiraj874u, please look at this question.                              http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440866/how-to-differentiate-received-messages-between-users-using-smack-and-java