# how to differentiate received messages between users using smack and java?

Tags: java, facebook, chat, smack

I am using servlets to send & receive chat messages to facebook  using smack .
In that  user's  "A" & "B"   are   chating with user "C".
If user "C" send's message  only to "A" ,that message also received by "B".
How to differenciate the messages between users?

finally my problem is ,to whom the message is cmg from facebook.

By using below code to   get messages:

```
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {

                 if ((message != null) && (message.getBody() != null)) {

                    System.out.println(chat.getParticipant() +"--"+ message.getBody());

                  }
            }
```

Comment: Message.getFrom() or Message.getTo()?

Answer (score 2):

Each `Message` object will contain a header and body. 
Header is basically a mapping of name value pairs. I would suggest to put userid in header of message.
Now in you chat client you can implement message filtering based user id in header.
This should resolve your issue.

Edit:

This link : http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26270&seqNum=6 has details on usage of header.

Comment: @user2709752: See my edit. I have provided a link which has details on how to set header.